# Loop twice but cost same time in JAVA

Tags: java, performance, loops

I have a loop like this:

```
  double[][] ED = new double[n][m];
  for(int k = 0; k < 20000; k++)
   for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++)
     ED[i][j] = dis(qx[k][i], qy[k][i], dx[k][j], dy[k][j]);
```

"dis" is a function to calculate the distance between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). Don't mind it. The problem is when I add another boolean assignment in the loop just like this:

```
  double[][] ED = new double[n][m];
  boolean[][] bool = new boolean[n][m];
   for(int k = 0; k < 20000; k++)
   for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++)
     {
       ED[i][j] = dis(qx[k][i], qy[k][i], dx[k][j], dy[k][j]);
       bool[i][j] = ED[i][j] > 5000;
     }
```

The new loop cost 1.5 time over the first one. I think it cost too much. For testing, I break 2 assignment into 2 loop.The strange thing happens, two cost of time are same. Sometimes, code 3 cost less time than code 2

```
    double[][] ED = new double[n][m];
    boolean[][] bool = new boolean[n][m];
    for(int k = 0; k < 20000; k++)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) 
       for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++)
        {
         ED[i][j] = dis(qx[k][i], qy[k][i], dx[k][j], dy[k][j]);
        }
      for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) 
       for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++)
        {
         bool[i][j] = ED[i][j] > 5000;
        }
    }
```

My aim is use as less time too calculate bool[i][j], how should I do.

Comment: Maybe the compiler is doing some optimization with the first loop as it can see that `k` is never used

Comment: k is used, different k will change qx qy dx dx, thanks, I will edit the question make it clear

Comment: It's difficult to guess what might be going on if you don't show the full code. What is done using k to get the qx,...dy? Other code has been omitted, too.

Comment: @Mark.zxx and how you measure your time? Do you include warmup runs etc? Microbenchmarking is not as easy as you may think

Comment: you override ED[i][j] for every iteration over k. Why? Maybe it should be ED[i][j] += or smth.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Tsivina because I omit some code, I use ED[i][j] to calculate something in every loop k. next time to override it is ok

Answer (score 1):

Introducing new, big array bool[][] may have more impact than it seems.
When only single arrayED[i][j] is used, you put less stress on L1 processor cache.
With second array, you have twice as much data, therefore cache will be invalidated more often.

Could you try, instead of using two arrays (bool and arrayED) use single array that holds both double and boolean? There will be significant overhead for array of Objects, but (maybe) compiler will be smart enough to destructure the Object.

With single array, you will have better data locality.

Also, as suggested in comments make sure you do your microbenchmarking properly.
Use http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/ and read its documentation how to use it correctly.

Another soltution that would help on multicore system is to use **parallel processing**. You may create `ThreadPoolExecutor` (with pool size equal to number of cores you have) then submit each opearation as task to the executor. Operation may be inner-most loop (with counter `j`) or even two inner-most loops (with counters `i` and `j`).
There will be some overhead for coordinating the work but execution time should be much faster if you have 4 or 8 cores.

Yet another idea is to change input data structure. Instead of operating on 4 two-dimensional arrays (`qx,qy,dx,dy`) could you have single array? it may make `dis` function faster.

Comment: I follow your advice, use a object that contains 2 arrays(boolean and double) but the cost time is just same before

Comment: 'use a object that contains 2 arrays'. I sugested one array of type Object, that will contain boolean and double.
Also, see edited answer for another solution (parallel processing)

Comment: ok, I try to use a Object[][] ,each object contains boolean and double. the cost is more than boolean[][] and double[][], about 20%.  Muitithread is the last method to improve performance, now I am looking for solution to rise single core performance.